# Unicorn and upstart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, unicorn, upstart

I'm having a hard time writing an upstart configuration file to start (and keep alive) the unicorn web server on a Ubuntu box.

How should I set the `respawn` and `expect` parameters? With `respawn` enabled the process is continously restarted (I see on top its PID changing continuously and the old one becoming zombie). If I remove the directive then the process isn't restarted when it dies.

According to the upstart documentation the expect parameter might be crucial: what's the unicorn fork-wise behaviour? Any clue?

Comment: I use `upstart` to start `god` which manages my `unicorns`. Everything's working like a charm :-)

Comment: Maybe I should try that. Can you point me to a god configuration script for `/etc/init`? Thanks!

Comment: Here's god's [page](http://godrb.com/). And here's my [upstart script](http://paste2.org/p/1871624).